# shell_exec with windows path not running

Tags: php, shell-exec

I am trying to run a command using shell_exec but its not returning any output. When I copy the command into command prompt it works like a charm.

Here is the command I'm trying to run.

```
$result = shell_exec('android update project -p "C:\xampp\htdocs\appBuilder" -t 1');
```

`$result` is returning an empty string. When I run the command in command prompt, it shows a message saying the `build.xml` file was generated successfully. It should be showing the success message in `$result`.

If I run just the command `android update project -p "C:\xampp\htdocs\appBuilder" -t 1` in command prompt, it works.

FYI: This command is to generate a `build.xml` file for an android application. I'm also running this on a local web server using xampp.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is happening, or not happening?  What do you expect?

Comment: could this be a simple path problem? where do you run the command while in command prompt? and have you tried running the same command from a diferent location?

Comment: After bumping my head around here and there, I re-started by computer and it worked :) Who knew? :)

Answer (score 3):

A **double backslash** `\\` should be used to print a single `\` character (first `\` is used to  escape the second `\`):

```
$result = shell_exec('android update project -p "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\appBuilder" -t 1');
```

Also make sure `PHP SAFE MODE` is set to `OFF`.