# Why doesn't shell-exec() run in PHP?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, shell-exec

I wanna run python code in PHP and the PHP code is bellow:

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('python3 /usr/C:/xampp/htdocs/scripts/a.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
print $output;
```

But, when I run this PHP code, nothing happens in the screen!

How can I fix it?

Comment: `shell_exec()` is usually disabled of servers by web hosting providers. Are you sure is enabled? Also, can you add after `<?php` this line `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Did you tried to execute the command in terminal? It works?

Comment: @GasKa How can I make sure whether it's enabled or not?

Comment: @Cosmin Yeah. It's ok

Comment: @Parisa using `function_exists`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: @GasKa I got this error:    "Notice: Undefined variable: shell_exec in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\a.php on line 3"

Answer (score 0):

If you say it works on the terminal and not on apache then apache's `php.ini` file may be disabling the use of `shell_exec()`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Your apache's `php.ini` file may look something like

```
disable_functions=exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen
```

Remove `shell_exec` from this list and restart the web server, although this is a security risk and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't because of `disable_functions` and the above code doesn't have any problem in Linux.

So, I think the problem is because of windows or the directory!

Comment: `shell_exec` should run on windows, more than likely the path is incorrect. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783649/shell-exec-with-windows-path-not-running

Comment: Try running something simple like: `echo this is a test`.

Comment: @nickl- There is no problem! I think the problem is with `shell_exec`!

Comment: Then we better fix it! What do you say... =)

Comment: @nickl- What do you mean?

Comment: You said: the problem is with shell_exec. So I said: Then we better fix it! What do you say... =) If it's broke we fix it, that's what we do. Any idea what is wrong with it?

Comment: @nickl- I tried many different things. But none of them gave me the right answer!

Comment: Edit your question and explain to us what you tried and what results you got. This will make it easier to assist you. `exec` is a different api method from `shell_exec` for executing shell commands, did you also try it.